# I have to implement hadoop, so it can process the data of call detail records?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins, hadoop-partitioning

I have configured HDFS, Datanode and namenode and also hbase. 
I have stored a CDR csv file in HDFS.  So how can I map it with Hbase and make ready to process it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `importtsv` tool to bulk load a CSV file into HBase. Here is a decent tutorial on how to do that: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/

The following is a summary of the blog post:

First, you create the table:

```
hbase shell 
create 'cdr', {NAME => 'f'},   {SPLITS => ['g', 'm', 'r', 'w']}
```

NAME specifies the name of the column family. Splits is just presplitting so its a bit faster. If this is CDR and the ROWKEY is going to be a phone number or something like that, you want to split on numbers, not characters. You just want to pick splits that actually split your data into chunks.

Then, you use importtsv to load the data from your cdr data cdr.csv:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-xxx.jar importtsv
-Dimporttsv.separator=,
-Dimporttsv.bulk.output=output
-Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:col2,f:col3,f:col4,... cdr cdr.csv
```

Then, to finish it:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles output wordcount
```

---

Note: you should think about what your rowkey is. Picking the first column is likely not the right choice. Remember, HBase isn't a relational database. Do something that makes sense in HBase.